# Application stops working after few calls to patch API

Tags: node.js, angular, express

My application has 2 screens. 1-dealer screen, 2-player screen. Dealer screen controls the game. Players can claim wins by pressing a button. A record is created in DB when claim win button is clicked. Dealer screen is constantly calling an API which retrieves all the win claims and displays on screen. Dealer can accept/reject a claim by pressing a button. Click of accept/reject button basically updates the status of the record in DB. This is working for the first 5-6 updates and then everything freezes and my application stops working.

What is wrong here? Is there any resources that I need to release after every update?

```
//accept/reject win claim API
router.patch('/winupdate/:ID', async(req, res, next)=>{

    try {
        const win = await Win.findOne({_id: req.params.ID})

        win.status = req.body.status

        await win.save()

    }catch {
        console.log("error while winupdate");
    }

});

//win accept/reject service
updWinClaim(claimResult, _id): Observable<any> {

  console.log("updWinClaim called for"+_id);

  return this.http.patch('api/winupdate/'+_id,claimResult);
}


    //retrieve all win claims
      getWinClaimss(p1) {

        console.log ("getWinClaimss-1 called");
        const source = timer(1,1000);

        const subscribe = source.subscribe(
          x => {this.winService.getWinClaimsByGame(p1)
                  .subscribe(
                    (data) => {this.winClaims = data;

                    console.log ("getWinClaimss-2 called");

            return this.winClaims;
          });
        });

  }

//code that calls update service
  winClaimRseult(_id,result){

    //console.log ("winClaimResult called with result= "+result);

    let newStatus = {
      id: _id,
      status: result
    };

    this.winService.updWinClaim(newStatus,_id)
      .subscribe(
        error => alert(error)
      );

  }
```

Comment: on more testing I am noticing that it's fine for 5 updates. As soon as 6th update is executed, everything stops working. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Neither update is throwing error nor my find is throwing error. Everything just stops working as soon as update is clicked 6th time. Any pointers is really appreciated. I don't know where to start looking.